# Cache updates after not related REST request completes

Tags: rest, caching, spring, aspect-oriented

I am wondering about the following scenario - it's in the land of Spring/AOP and Ehcache.

Happens in REST Web Application - REST/Service/DAO layers - I have objects in cache (`@Repository` + `@Cacheable`). Upon particular REST request (let's call it `/notUpdateRelated`) execution, after the request completes successfully (in this case it's enough not to throw an exception), I have to update the cache.
Calls on the `/notUpdateRelated` endpoint may happen from different threads.

So I've researched a couple of options:

1. The direct approach would be to expose thread-safe cache eviction method and modify the `/notUpdateRelated` service code. This way, before the controller returns from execution of the `/notUpdateRelated` request, I can trigger the cache eviction.

What I don't like about this approach is that, as you might have guessed, it's not responsibility of the `/notUpdateRelated` service to evict the cache. Sadly the cache eviction is required only for this service call and there's no chance for other services to have to do it.

2. I can use AOP's `@After` annotation (After returning advice) and do the same as above. This way the modification of the `/notUpdateRelated` service will be minimal.

What I don't like about this approach is that this is not a true cross-cutting concern for the application classes.

3. I can use `Interceptor`/`Filter` on the response of `/notUpdateRelated` and trigger the cache eviction there, but this feels like misuse of the above objects.

   There are possible approaches I am not familiar with. I will be happy to consider anything better.
   What do you think is the best approach in this situation?